# Suggestions on providing HA access to an external (fibre) RAID subsystem

Tags: linux, high-availability, cluster

We are looking at upgrading our storage capacity with an external RAID subsystem that has redundant (2) fibre controllers, each controller has 4 x 8 Gbps fibre ports. I would like to make access to this storage system occur via HA Linux.

Ideally I would connect 2 fibre ports from each controller into each Linux server, and then export either NFS or iSCSI via a 10 Gbe interface.

I have seen plenty of references to DRBD, however all of those references tend to use block storage that is solely attached to each machine, rather than having a shared block storage device, so I am unsure if DRBD could (or should) be used in this case.

Ideas?

Comment: Sounds like maybe you should have purchased redundant NAS units with 10GbE interfaces rather than FC units that are using *nix boxes as an intermediary that turns them into NAS storage.

Comment: redundant NAS units aren't generally able to run in an HA mode, yes, they can backup to each other but if virtual servers are connected to the NAS then when the NAS goes down any servers connected to that NAS are screwed.

Comment: AFAIK, NetApp, EMC, HP, and IBM all offer this functionality is at least some of their product line. I'm sure there are other too, those are just off the top of my head.

Comment: I wouldn't really call anything NetApp offers a NAS unit, all of the NetApp servers (V series and FAS series) are both NAS and SAN units, and require additional disk shelves (read SAN connectivity) to offer HA type options. I imagine this is also true of EMC, HP, IBM solutions. A fully redundant system from these places is >> $50K and will still use Fibre or SAS interconnects to the shelf storage.

Comment: They all offer CIFS/NFS connectivity to the clustered storage. What exactly is your definition of NAS? The most common definition is that it offers file level access over a network where a SAN offers block storage. If you have unusual requirements you should state them

Comment: yes, they do all offer NAS functionality but to call them "NAS units" is a gross simplification. A typical NAS unit is something you would find from DROBO, QNAP, Synology, Buffalo, Netgear, etc. These units are inexpensive frequently < $1K contain the disk in a single appliance and present the storage over the network.

In the end what I am trying to do is essentially to replicate the NetApp functionality with *nix boxes, as that is what NetApp does. their own OS boots off of FreeBSD! I just don't want to pay as much as NetApp charges!

Comment: Ah, well that makes more sense and you should have put all of that in your original answer :) Also, just an FYI, you have a *very* narrow definition of NAS. What you list is generally a SOHO NAS. That doesn't mean that people don't deploy dedicated NetApp or other type of filers as 100% NAS just for something like NFS for Oracle. SAN means shared block level storage. NAS means shared file level storage. That's the only difference :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to present file storage to your network, get NAS units, not SAN.

Comment: NAS units don't offer the Failover that I am looking for. The block storage is generally inside of them so if you need to take one offline (for upgrade or other reasons) it means bringing the entire filesystem offline for some amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a combination of a heartbeat solution like [keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org/) or [ucarp](http://www.pureftpd.org/project/ucarp)... and a virtual IP setup for client access to the two Linux servers. Some form of [fencing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fencing_%28computing%29) to use the nodes in an active/standby capacity.

Can you elaborate on your storage server setup and what tools you have available to you?

A more polished option is to use a ZFS filer as a NAS head to present the backend block storage to clients via a variety of protocols (iSCSI, Fibre, NFS, CIFS). [NexentaStor](http://nexenta.com/corp/products/what-is-openstorage/nexentastor) is great for this. This is a common use-case for repurposing legacy SAN storage. Plus, you'd have the option of using Nexenta's cluster/HA solution to handle high-availability.

Comment: I can't elaborate much more at this point. However, this looks like a solution that might work. We are definitely in a situation where fiscal resources are minimal for this kind of stuff. Overtime we have acquired various (non-homogenious) Fibre RAID storage units. Thanks!